# How can someone achieve GRE waiver?

Tags: computer-science, united-states, gre

How can somebody get an admission in a graduate science/technology/engineering program US university without GRE?

Comment: Waivers from a university or department admission requirement would be the prerogative of the university's or department's admissions officers. Policies will vary between different universities or even between different departments in the same university. You need to ask the admissions officers at the place you want to apply to.

Comment: You should have a reason for requesting the GRE waiver.   If you don't explain this, the admissions committee will probably assume that you didn't submit a GRE score because you did very badly on the GRE or were afraid to take it in the first place.  There are some reasonable excuses for not taking the GRE, such as "I couldn't take the GRE in my country due to an ongoing civil war."

Comment: Unless this question is completely hypothetical, you will probably get more helpful answers if you can explain why you want to do this. Otherwise, you are just asking people to list every possible waiver reason, and if your particular reason is not listed, you won't know whether that's because it's not an acceptable reason, or just because nobody thought to mention it.

Comment: You could always apply to a department (like mine) that doesn't require GRE scores at all.

Comment: Hey guys, are going to put every question of mine on hold and thus systematically kick me out of academia.se?

Comment: @BROY: You're getting a lot of close votes because a lot of your recent questions have been falling into the pattern of being opinion-based ("Is a PhD better than two masters?") or too specific (asking about "empirical research," then pointing to a specific advertisement). I think people are looking at the questions, not the poster.

Comment: @aeismail, now what about this question? is it general enough now?

Comment: I had already reopened it when I posted the comment.

Answer (score 3):

At this level of generality, I think all one can say is the following:

- Look for programs that do not have a GRE as part of their admission requirements.
- For departments that do require it: if you have some specific reason for being unable to take the GRE, or for not having scores that meet their criteria, contact someone at the department and ask how to proceed.  (Admissions information normally includes the email address of a contact person.)  In many cases, you will include some explanation in your cover letter or statement of purpose.
- If a department requires the GRE, and you don't have a compelling reason for not taking it, or for doing poorly: don't apply to that department.